# JPA Query - OnetoMany with restriction on many side

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

I want to execute a JPA query linking Partnership (1) to Partners
(many).  I want all the Partners for the specified Partnership No and specified year.

Query 1 - does not work, brings back all Partners for all years

```
query = "SELECT p FROM Partnership p"
  + " JOIN p.partners prt"
  + " WHERE prt.id.prtSchemeYear=:sYear"
  + " AND p.pspHerd=:herd")
```

Query 2 - also does not work - same all Partners returned whereas only 2015 asked for

```
query = "select distinct p from Partnership p"
      + " JOIN p.partners prt with (prt.id.prtSchemeYear=:sYear)"
      + " WHERE p.pspHerd=:herd")

{result - Partners for all years returned even though 2015 specified in :sYear, yes, restricted by herd using pk psp_cust_id
```

**ONE - Partnership**
    private long pspCustId;   {this is PK (ie) @Id)
    private String pspHerd;
    private Set partners = new HashSet(0)

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "partnership")
public Set<Partner> getPartners() {
    return this.partners;
}
```

**MANY - Partner**
    private PartnerId id;   {composite PK class}
    private Owner ownerByPrtPreviousOwnId;
    private Partnership partnership;
    private Owner ownerByPrtOwnId;
    private long prtHolding;

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name = "prtSchemeYear", column = @Column(name =
  "PRT_SCHEME_YEAR", nullable = false, precision = 4, scale = 0)),
@AttributeOverride(name = "prtHerd", column = @Column(name = "PRT_HERD",
    nullable = false, length = 8)),
@AttributeOverride(name = "prtOwnId", column = @Column(name = 
    "PRT_OWN_ID", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)) })
    public PartnerId getId() {
        return this.id;
}
```

**PK Class**
PartnerId
    @Embeddable
    public class PartnerId implements java.io.Serializable {
        private short prtSchemeYear;
        private String prtHerd;
        private long prtOwnId;

Named Queries I have tried
- Get Partnership with Partners for the Herd and Year specified (2015)

The resultant SQL for T_PARTNERS is not including any restriction by Year only psp_cust_id (which is a foreign key)

thanks if you can help